# React mui - setting textarea to take the height of the parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the [react mui library](https://v3.material-ui.com/api/text-field/) v3.9.3 for UI components in my project. I have a textarea field:

```
  <div className={classes.fieldWrappper}>
    <TextField
      id="filled-multiline-static"
      label="Oppgavetekst"
      multiline
      value={tekst}
      onChange={onTekstChange}
      InputProps={{classes: {root: classes.textArea}}}
      InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: true,
      }}/>
  </div>
```

I have set the styling of the `fieldWrapper` and `textArea` like this:

```
fieldWrappper: {
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'grid',
  },
  textArea: {
    height: '100%',
    background: 'white',
  },
```

But, the textarea doesn't take the whole height of the `fieldWrapper`. You can see that here:

[image]

It looks like MuiInputBase has gotten the full height of the parent element.

[image]

In the console element inspector, I can see that if I change the `MuiPrivateTextarea-root` to have height `100%`, than the textarea takes the full height. But, I don't see any examples where and how can I do that in the code?

Comment: Why do you want `display: grid` for fieldWrapper ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is super late, but hopefully it helps anyone who stumbles across this looking to implement a full height text area with Material.

If you place your TextField inside a flex container, you can enlarge the root element with FlexGrow and then use `InputProps` to make the input element take up the full height. `alignItems: 'start'` is required so that your text sits at the top of the input field.

```
<TextField
    multiline
    sx={{display: 'flex', flexGrow: 1}}
    InputProps={{
      sx: {
        height: '100%',
        alignItems: 'start'
      }
    }}
  />
```